# Simplying SQLalchemy queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLalchemy query syntax is verbose:

```
models.session.query(models.Person).filter(models.Person.first_name == 'David').all()
```

I've read several guides implying table objects have query method, but can't find it in the SQLalchemy docs, nor make it work in my code. Is there any reason why I shouldn't use code like below?

```
class QueryMethod:
    @classmethod
    def filter(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return session.query(cls).filter(*args, **kwargs).all()


class Person(Base, QueryMethod):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(255))
```

New query syntax allowed by this inherritance:

```
models.Person.filter(models.Person.first_name=='David')
```

My question: is there a way to remove the 'models.Person' bit inside the filter method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [`filter_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by). The query would be something like

```
session.query(models.Person).filter_by(first_name="foo")
```

The `filter` classmethod that you have used harcodes the `session`. I would recommend that you pass the session explicitly to it so that the same query can be re-used over different sessions.

Comment: Hard-coded `session` is fine if `session` is a `scoped_session`. Also he'll have to add the `filter_by` method to his `QueryMethod`.